# How can i get domain-name instead of ip-address using nginx in ubuntu?

Tags: nginx

I complete the configuration in nginx as well as i connect it via this link

**http://1.2.3.4/MyProject/**

where my ip address assign in nginx 1.2.3.4

and my nginx configuration

```
server_name 1.2.3.4;
listen 80;
```

but when i give domain name like

```
server name account.com;
listen 80;
```

but when i open that page from browser like:-    http://account.come it will redirect at http://:1.2.3.4/myproject

so how can i hide my ip-address and see my domain name?

Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove any server_name 1.2.3.4;   in all config files and also see default config file under site-availeables

to check why its redirect to ip please check yor DNS server for example bind or bind9 service or named: /etc/named and all zones under /var/lib/named

maybe new site not configured proper by you then ping sitename once in your client system like windows and once by lynx on server via putty...

2-check nginx is working with proxycache or module cache ??

3-check your project code setting for example wordpress or some projects redirect some pages to cached url on database...

to check is from this project make test.php and code about echo rand(1,999); that can test redirection and cache at once.
ifrandom code show same number it is cache problem.
if no cache but redirecting to server ip address it is configuration issue...

if not solved remove all http server configs and  define again .
add with www alias for site name

```
server {
listen 80 ;
server_name a.com www.a.com;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had got the solution for that, I changed my godady account configuration.

and then put like:-

server_name abc.com;

Comment: HI gabbar vicksy. What did u changed in the godday account configuration. I'm stuckup with same problem. Please help me. It will be very greatful  for me thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @AjayKumar I have added domain name in godaddy account